# How Can I Do This In Lighttpd?

Tags: lighttpd

This is for Apache:
    `<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">`
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
    `</FilesMatch>`

How do I do it for lighttpd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should acutally be quite easy with a regular expression on `$HTTP["url"]` and `mod_setenv`:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$" {
  setenv.add-response-header = ( "Cache-Control" => "max-age=290304000, public" )
}
```

If you need to manipulate the requests or responses in more detail, you should dig into [mod_magnet](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModMagnet).

Documentation hints:

- [Configuration file for the core module](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:Configuration)
- [mod_setenv](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModSetEnv)

Comment: I think the semantics of setenv.add-response-header in lighttpd and "Header set" in apache are different. The former adds a header, even if it already exists. The latter replaces what was in the header, or adds it if it was not present before.